# Should I use the api response DTO in the view layer in multi-client Angular frontend?

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, design-patterns, dto

I am aware of the benefits of using a DTO (data transfer object) for rest APIs response instead of responding with the Entity DAO(data access object) to avoid coupling between the data layer and the frontend and I am thinking of applying the same pattern to my angular frontend app where my view layer has an Angular client and an Ionic client.

For example if the Backend returns this object

```
export interface Bill {
  accountNo: string;
  accountId: string;
  accountType: string;
  totalAmountDue: string;
  primary: boolean;
}
```

But I want to show different partial data for the Angular client and the Ionic client should I use the `Bill` interface in both or create to seperate ViewModel interfaces like the DTO and DAO pattern ?

```
export interface BillAngularViewModel {
  accountNo: string;
  accountId: string;
}
```

```
export interface BillIonicViewModel {
 totalAmountDue: string;
  primary: boolean;
}
```

tried reading into the DTO and Backend For Frontend design patterns but nothing seems to be applicable within the frontend only